# How to use go-github to post a comment on a Github issue?

Tags: go, github-api, go-github

I want to use https://github.com/google/go-github for creating a comment on an issue, but this test code fails:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "github.com/google/go-github/v49/github"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
        &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: "token_here"},
    )
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)

    client := github.NewClient(tc)

    // list all repositories for the authenticated user
    repos, _, err := client.Repositories.List(ctx, "", nil)
}
```

but I'm just getting

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:9:9: undefined: context
./main.go:18:2: repos declared but not used
./main.go:18:12: err declared but not used
```

back...
So - what I have to do to get this working and how can I send a comment (via my token) to an issue on github?

Comment: Please take the [Tour of  Go](https://tour.golang.org/) to get a good overview of basic Go syntax, variable usage, and value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./main.go:9:9: undefined: context
```

You need to import the `"context"` package to be able to call `context.Background()`

```
./main.go:18:2: repos declared but not used
./main.go:18:12: err declared but not used
```

After calling `client.Repositories.List(ctx, "", nil)` you created 2 new variables: `repos` and `err`, but never used them anywhere. In Go, an unused variable is a compiler error, so either remove those variables, or preferably use them as you would.

> So - what i have to do to get this working and how can i send a comment (via my token) to an issue on github?

To use the Github API, you will need to get yourself an [access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), and replace `"token_here"` with that. Then you can do something as follows:

```golang
comment := &github.IssueComment{
    Body: github.String("Hello, world!"),
}
comment, _, err := client.Issues.CreateComment(
    context.Background(), 
    "OWNER", 
    "REPO", 
    ISSUE_NUMBER, 
    comment,
)
if err != nil {
    // handle any errors
}
```

... where `OWNER` is the owner of the repository, `REPO` is the name of the repository, and `ISSUE_NUMBER` is the number of the issue where you want to write the comment.

Comment: This is really helpful but i can't get the issue number working, caused by `./main.go:21:19: cannot use "28" (untyped string constant) as int64 value in argument to github.Int64` but thx for your help!

Comment: That's because "28" is a string type, and it is expecting an int64 type. I would recommend learning Go, as well as some basic programming skills before attempting what you are trying to do. I think even some basic knowledge would help you out.

Comment: thx again @robbieperry22 !
i just used `ISSUE_NUMBER := int(issueNumber)` for conversion and it works :-)